# Is it possible to run Blazor (Webassembly!) on mobile devices as apps?

Tags: mobile, blazor, webassembly

Company needs to decide about future frontend technology and I was asked by the big man to determine if Blazor (using Webassembly) is for us.

I fully agree with Blazor / Webassembly because it's so easy to use that even backend developers can develop frontend stuff quickly enough (as opposed to things like react.js and angular, which are based around Javascript or the very similar Typescript).

But...

We need to create a mobile application from our web frontend as well, because people will want to use our frontend on the go (a lot, actually... our product is meant for people to enhance their "outdoor experience" about their home).

Any chance to run a Blazor / Webassembly app in the browser on mobile devices?

To give more information about this: there is a complication - we need to run a tiny bit of native code, too, when indoors, because of a specific requirement regarding "offline operation". Thats actually why I ask - if it was only about "show website X in browser" I wouldn't need to ask, but we need to actually implement some "local only" functionality.

Comment: Yes, Blazor can be configured as PWA, this will allow the app to function offline, however that will not enable you to run native code. Regarding browsers, nothing will allow you to run native code directly... otherwise you might be able to do run the app and native code on mobile with Electron and Cordova, but I don't know how that works

Comment: You may also look into the blazor mobile bindings and maui

Comment: Asking for recommendations isn't an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.  That said, I agree with @PatrickBeynio that Blazor is great for turning standard websites into an app (PWA).  The advantages are that it runs on multiple devices (windows, ios, android) and doesn't need to go through the lengthy approval process of a native app. Yet, PWA run with limited permissions and are not appropriate for every use, e.g., banking.

Comment: What did you finally decide?

Comment: To go with react js. I'm not doing any frontend stuff anyway so I let the head of frontend decide and this was what he said.